# Print object from singly linked list

Tags: java

I have an object that stores a few ints and a string. I assign this object to a SLL here:

```
BirthdayCalc object = new BirthdayCalc(month, day, year, result, birthdayStr);
                    
                    
list.addLast(object);
```

How would I print out specific parts of this object in the SLL? I want to read the element from the node, and then take month day and year, and birthday string. Since this object is created in a loop I need to be able to print the element of each new node.

Answer (score 1):

Your Linkedlist can be given the type safety of the BirthdayCalc class objects

```
List<BirthdayCalc> ll = new LinkedList<>();
```

Now since you need to only print the specific properties you can you use a for-each loop:

```
for( BirthdayCalc bc : ll ) {
    System.out.println(bc.month +" "+ bc.year+" "+bc. birthdayStr);
}
```

You can alternatively use iterator as well. Moreover, access the properties using Getter and Setter methods.